# How to show a formattedValue instead of the userEnteredValue in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have been trying to add a value in a cell of google sheets from a service account and show a formatted text to the viewers. Like, the value can be 1 but I will show "John" instead of it.
So I followed the documentation and found the request updateCell in the batch_update where there was an option to show the "formattedValue".

> formattedValue
>
> string
>
> The formatted value of the cell. This is the value as it's shown to
>   the user. This field is read-only.

So here's what I tried-

```py
req = []

req.append({
         "updateCells": {
              "rows": [
                  {
                     "values": [
                        {
                           "userEnteredValue": {
                                "numberValue": 17
                           },
                           "formattedValue": "ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser",
                           "userEnteredFormat": {
                                 "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                                 "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE"            
                           },
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "fields": "*",
               "range": {
                     "sheetId": sheet.get_worksheet(0).id,
                     "startRowIndex": 0,
                     "endRowIndex": 1,
                     "startColumnIndex": 0,
                     "endColumnIndex": 1
               }
          }
      })

sheet.batch_update({"requests":req})
```

But it doesn't work and shows the userEnteredValue. What am I doing wrong? Or this is just not what formattedValue is supposed to do? If it is the case then what should I do to achieve my task?

Comment: In your request body, the value of `17` is put to the cell. But in your question, you want to retrieve the formatted value. If you want to retrieve the formatted values, I think that you can use the method of spreadsheets.values.get in Sheets API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) But I cannot understand about your question. So can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for replying. What I want to do is to show some text/string to the viewer instead of the actual value of a cell. But I would like to retrieve actual value later. Example- actual value of the cell is 17 but viewer will see the text "ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser". I would like to retrieve the value 17 later in my program.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I can understand about `actual value of the cell is 17`. But I cannot understand about `viewer will see the text "ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser"`. Especially, I cannot understand about `viewer`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for my bad English skill too. That was just a figure of speech. Gist is "ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser" is the value that would be apparent in the sheet and the userEnteredValue would remain hidden.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the formatted value instead of the original value from the cell on Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about using the method of spreadsheets.values.get in Sheets API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. This will help later in my program. But right now, why the formattedValue that I am passing is not apparent in the sheet but the userEnteredValue is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212232/discussion-between-sadman-sakib-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the value of `17` as the original value and you want to show `ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser` as the displayed value in the cell.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In order to achieve above goal, please use `numberFormat` instead of `formattedValue`.

When your request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```
req.append({
    "updateCells": {
        "rows": [{
            "values": [{
                "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 17
                },
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                    "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE",
                    "numberFormat": {
                        "pattern": "\"ThisShouldBeShownToTheUser\"",
                        "type": "NUMBER"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }],
        "fields": "*",
        "range": {
            "sheetId": sheet.get_worksheet(0).id,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 1
        }
    }
})
```

#### Note:

- About `formattedValue`, for example, when the date object is put in a cell and set the format of the date, the display value can be retrieved with `formattedValue` instead of the date object. I think that this is the same with the method of `getDisplayValue()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())

#### References:

- [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#numberformat)
- [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)